# Touch a button behind an invisible view

Tags: android, button, view, touch

[image]

See the picture, i have a button and it is behind an invisible view (the red line), lets say a gridview, or just simply `LinearLayout`. Is there any possible way that will let me touch or click the button behind this invisible view? Thank you.

**NOTE :** i have my reason why i need the button behind the view, i just illustrated it using this picture for you guys to know what i meant. The button has to behind the view :))

Comment: add a transparent button on the linearlayout and make sure it overlay your visible button.

Comment: that's a good idea @LazyNinja ill try it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

Declare it in your layout.

Let me know if it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes Its possible. Until or unless your invisible view is not clickable. so check your invisible layout structure. make `android:clickable="false"`

Comment: the view on the front will also contain some buttons and i need the button also to be clickable.

Comment: all the button are working only the layout click will be disable.

Answer (score 0):

1 way you can do this is:
    1. add an `onTouch(View view, MotionEventevent)` Listener to your layout
    2. get the buttons bounds
    3. Check if the touch event was done inside the bounds

The code should look something like this:

```
Button button;
Rect rect;

onCreate(){
rect = button.getClipBounds();
layout.setOnTouchListener(this)
}

onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event){
    if(rect.contains(event.getX(), event.getY())
        //insert action here
}
```

Comment: Good only if button is static