# Android - Click buttons through a viewpager

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have a layout that contain two items. A `RelativeLayout` with several buttons inside it and a `ViewPager`. But, I can't click the buttons since the buttons are behind the `ViewPager`. Is there a way so I can click the buttons behind the `ViewPager`? Here's my layout.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_down_toolbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:splitMotionEvents="true"
        android:id ="@+id/content_container">

        (Buttons)

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: you must explain about your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question.

Comment: similar http://stackoverflow.com/a/20320946/6668797

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to do it by dispatching the touch event from the Viewpager to the content_container like this.

```
viewpager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            content_container.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Thanks for the answers.